# Cancel while on WorldPay

Tags: expresso-store

I currently have Store (1.6.4) up and running amazingly. However, I've just spotted that if a user clicks cancel while on worldpay then I get a callback failure alert:

```
Error reported: Callback to https://capuk.org/?ACT=35&H=8ea9360d3687aa3ae10091b4fa2be74c: NOT OK, recevied HTTP status: 302 
Server Reference: mg4imsps3p:callbackFailureEmail-122700:MerchReq-870-97
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Which version of Store are you running?

Comment: I'm using Store 1.6.4 - the latest as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Is this still happening for you Dan? If so can you email support@exp-resso.com so we can take a look at your site?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've just sent across an email now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug. It's probably best if you email support@exp-resso.com so we can investigate this directly on your website.